# Problem logging into my docker mysql database container: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to log into mysql in my database docker container. But I can't log in with the credentials I gave. I get this error message:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Here is the relevant part of my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - "./dbdata:/home"
```

What do I have to change so that I can successfully log on to mysql?

Comment: What's the command you are using for connect to mysql?

Comment: Using `MYSQL_PWD=password mysql   -u "root"  -h localhost -P 3306` (not recommanded) or ` mysql   -u "root"  -h localhost -P 3306 -p` should word.

Comment: @DrClaw `mysql -u root -p` from inside the database container

Comment: It's working fine for me. Are you sure you are using the password: **password**? Try this `MYSQL_PWD="password" mysql -u root`. And since you bind the port you can do it directly from your host, you don't need to go inside the container.

Comment: @DrClaw if i changed the image from mariadb to mysql:5.7.24 then it work fine to me, too. It could be that the problem occurs the i used mariadb image?

Comment: i have no idea why it's working with mysql and not mariadb.